# Weird error message when using mutate()/case_when()

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new variable in R using mutate/case_when and I'm running into a weird error. If I run this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(dist = c(rep(seq(-50,50,1), each = 50)))
temp <- df %>%
  mutate(bins = case_when(dist>=-50 & dist<-40 ~ -45,
                          dist>=-40 & dist<-30 ~ -35,
                          dist>=-30 & dist<-20 ~ -25,
                          dist>=-20 & dist<-10 ~ -15,
                          dist>=-10 & dist<0 ~ -5,
                          dist>=0 & dist<10 ~ 5,
                          dist>=10 & dist<20 ~ 15,
                          dist>=20 & dist<30 ~ 25,
                          dist>=30 & dist<40 ~ 35,
                          dist>=40 ~ 45))
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `bins`.
x could not find function "&<-"
ℹ Input `bins` is `case_when(...)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've used mutate/case_when so often and have never seen anything like this.

Comment: Add a space between the `<-` symbols (i.e. to `< -`) so they are interpreted as "less than negative x" instead of "assign x to dist".

Comment: This fixes it and I understand what was happening now -- thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

why not simply this (use only one sided condition and case_when will evaluate it giving preference to former conditions )

```
temp <- df %>%
  mutate(bins = case_when(dist < -40 ~ -45,
                          dist < -30 ~ -35,
                          dist < -20 ~ -25,
                          dist < -10 ~ -15,
                          dist < 0 ~ -5,
                          dist < 10 ~ 5,
                          dist < 20 ~ 15,
                          dist < 30 ~ 25,
                          dist < 40 ~ 35,
                          dist >= 40 ~ 45))
```